# Consequences of changing domain name

Tags: drupal

We are considering to change our domain name from:

**reallylongandnotuserfriendly.example.com**

to:

**you.example.com**

We have a Drupal 7 site. What are the consequences / fixes we need to be aware of, to not harm our CiviCRM installation?

Answer (score 4):

Aside from any customizations, you should:

1. Check your civicrm.settings.php file to fix the base URL.  (And double-check that your path hasn't changed).
2. Go to Administer - System Settings - Clear Caches and Update Paths and clear your caches and update your paths.
3. Confirm that the Resource URLs look right (they should be fine as a result of step 2).
4. Make sure you get a SSL certificate for your new domain name if you had one for your old domain name.

Comment: It probably goes without saying, but also make sure to forward any traffic from the long URL to the new URL.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Andrew's answer, be aware that this may break your IPNs.  See [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/473/how-to-change-paypal-ipn-url-when-migrating-civicrm-onto-a-new-domain) for how to mitigate this.